# Compute the integral $\iiint e^{-l|p|}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}d^3p $

Tags: integration

I need compute the integral

$$(2\pi)^{-3} \int d^3p e^{-l|p|}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}$$

The problem does not specified the limits of integration

The result is

$$\frac{1}{\pi^2} \frac{l}{\sqrt{\vec{x}^2+l^2}}$$

I saw the references about t-Student and I had not achieved it.

I have tried to split the integral as

$$\int dp_x dp_y dp_z e^{-l\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}} e^{ip_xx+ip_yy+ip_zz}$$

x2 without result.

Also I tried to insert a 2D dirac Delta and after integrate only in dp instead dp^2. Also without result

Could you help me to solve this integral?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have corrected it. However, still i had not achieve the calculus

Comment: If no limits of integration are explicitly specified, the default assumption is that it's over the entire parameter space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. This is a common physics shorthand in classical electrodynamics (and beyond).

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, i have assumed that $p_i \in ]-\infty,\infty[$ in my calculation....without results....

Comment: For the special case $x=0$, the stated result reduces to $1/\pi^2$, which is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with Quanto's answer. Alexis, where did your "The result is $\frac{1}{\pi^2} \frac{l}{\sqrt{\vec{x}^2+l^2}}$" come from?

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, let $\vec x= (0,0,|x|)$ and integrate as follows

\begin{align}
\frac1{(2\pi)^{3} }\int_{{\Bbb R}^3} e^{-l|p|}e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}} d^3p =& \ \frac1{(2\pi)^{2} }\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi 
e^{-lp + i |x|p\cos\theta}p^2 \sin\theta d\theta dp\\
=& \ \frac1{2\pi^{2}|x| }\int_0^\infty
e^{-lp}p\sin(|x|p)dp\\
=&\ \frac1{\pi^{2} }\frac l{(|x|^2+l^2)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much